# Adding Custom Header in AngularJs upon bootstrapping

Tags: angularjs, authentication, dependency-injection, auth-token

Suppose I have an angular app called `chococalateApp` that depends on 3 other modules, namely `Product`, `Sales` and `LogIn`.

Now, my app is building on RESTful API. Upon successful login, the server will respond by sending back an authentication token. I would like to append this token as a custom header `X-AUTH` whenever `$http` services are used. Since all my REST API requires the auth token, I would need to append this header in every `$http` request. This is doable by configuring the $httpProvider, as shown below:

```
angular.module('chocolateApp',['Product','Sales','Login'])
  .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
     $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-AUTH'] = 'randomkeybyserver'
 }
])
```

My question is, can I inject the value of the auth-token **AFTER** the module has been bootstrapped?

For example, I have a service in `LogIn` module that is able to do the authentication, and retrieved the required token. How do I pass the token back to my main `chocolateApp` module and configure it? Will this result in circular dependency, or is it that my understanding of DI is wrong here?

If this is not achievable, how should this be designed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it from your `Login` service after authentication and it will be available across your app.

```
login: function(...) {
    $http.post(...).then(function(response) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common['X-AUTH'] = response.data.randomkeybyserver;
    });
}
```

Comment: hi @Puigcerber, I have questions regarding instantiated services and providers. For your method, once the users had log in but hit the refreshed button, the service will collapse and the token will be gone. Is there anyway I can do it so the token will persist?

Comment: You could use [$cookieStore](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore) to persist it but remember that your token should be encrypted so nobody can modify it to gain access to your app.